# Python access a string value within data frame iterrows and check if it contains a specific value is returning generic error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access the string value of `df.loc[idx, "GDP"]` but on different field called `Quarter`.

So while I am within `df.loc[idx, "GDP"]`, and to check if string in `Quarter` related to `df.loc[idx, "GDP"]` contain `2008`. I tried the following:

```
for idx, gdp in df.iterrows():
        if df.loc[idx, df['Quarter'].str[0:4]]==2008 and (idx<=length-2) and (df.loc[idx, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+1, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+2, "GDP"]):
            listOfQuarters.append({"GDP": df.loc[idx+1, "GDP"], "Quarter": df.loc[idx+1, "Quarter"]})
            print(df.loc[idx, df[ 'Quarter'].str[0:4])
```

Adding the following line `df.loc[idx, df['Quarter'].str[0:4]==2008`, caused a generic error without specifying what is it about.

P.S. I know it is a good practice to loop over data frames this way, but the total rows is 66 so this is fine for now.

Comment: Can u include some sample input along with expected output.

Comment: You should review the section about [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)... if you put a comma inside `.loc` then pandas evaluates anything after that as a column indexer... try `df[(df.index==idx) & (cond2) & ...]`

Comment: And this is just a duplicate of your earlier question from today...